# Why recomposition happens when call ViewModel in a callback?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, android-viewmodel, compose-recomposition

I completely confused with compose conception.
I have a code

```java
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: HomeViewModel = getViewModel()) {
    Scaffold {
        val isTimeEnable by viewModel.isTimerEnable.observeAsState()
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Black),
        ) {
            Switch(
                checked = isTimeEnable ?: false,
                onCheckedChange = {
                    viewModel.setTimerEnable(it)
                },
            )
            Clock(viewModel.timeSelected.value!!) {
                viewModel.setTime(it)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Clock(date: Long, selectTime: (date: Date) -> Unit) {
    NumberClock(Date(date)) {
        val time = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.ROOT).format(it)
        Timber.d("Selected time: time")
        selectTime(it)
    }
}
```

Why `Clock` widget recomposes when I tap switch. If I remove line `selectTime(it)` from `Clock` widget callback recomposition doesn't happen.
Compose version: 1.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in terms of compose, you are creating a new `selectTime` lambda every time, so recomposition is necessary. If you pass `setTime` function as a reference, compose will know that it is the same function, so no recomposition is needed:

```kotlin
Clock(viewModel.timeSelected.value!!, viewModel::setTime)
```

---

Alternatively if you have more complex handler, you can [`remember`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables) it. Double brackets (`{{ }}`) are critical here, because you need to remember the lambda.

```kotlin
Clock(
    date = viewModel.timeSelected.value!!,
    selectTime = remember(viewModel) {
        {
            viewModel.setTimerEnable(it)
        }
    }
)
```

I know it looks kind of strange, you can use [`rememberLambda`](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/949629d5a45fe524707ee02b55e0338d) which will make your code more readable:

```
selectTime = rememberLambda(viewModel) {
    viewModel.setTimerEnable(it)
}
```

Note that you need to pass all values that may change as keys, so `remember` will be recalculated on demand.

---

In general, recomposition is not a bad thing. Of course, if you can decrease it, you should do that, but your code should work fine even if it is recomposed many times. For example, you should not do heavy calculations right inside composable to do this, but instead use [side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

So if recomposing `Clock` causes weird UI effects, there is probably something wrong with your `NumberClock` that cannot survive the recomposition. If so, please add the `NumberClock` code to your question for advice on how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behaviour. You are clearly modifying the `isTimeEnabled` field inside your viewmodel when the user toggles the switch (by calling vm.setTimeenabled). Now, it is apparent that the `isTimeEnabled` in your viewmodel is a `LiveData` instance, and you are referring to that instance from within your Composable by calling `observeAsState` on it. Hence, when you modify the value from the switch's onValueChange, you are essentially modifying the state that the Composable depends on. Hence, to render the updated state, a recomposition is triggered