# Jetpack compose button action onClick leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-jetpack-compose

we've encountered a problem with Jetpack Compose button actions leaking. We provide a class with resources (e.g strings, colors, and BUTTON ACTIONS):

```
data class CameraOnBoardingComposeViewResources(val title: String, val buttonTitle: String, val buttonAction: () -> Unit)
```

This data class is created in the fragment like so:

```
val resources = CameraOnBoardingComposeViewResources(
    "Title", "ButtonTitle"
) { navigate() }
```

And in our composable we use those resources like so:

```
@Composable
fun composeOnBoardingView(resources: CameraOnBoardingComposeViewResources) {
    Surface(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
        color = colorResource(R.color.idenfyMainColorV2),
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(42.dp)
            .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
            .clickable(onClick = resources.buttonAction)
            .fillMaxWidth()
    )
}
```

The problem is that buttonAction leaks. How can we avoid this leak, should we somehow dispose of it, or do we need to change this architecture a bit?

**EDIT After CommonsWare**

Ok, I’ve located the problem, and it is indeed inside the composeOnBoardingView composable. It’s this code snippet:

```
val currentInstructionDescription: MutableState<String> = remember {
   mutableStateOf("")
}

val progress = remember { mutableStateOf(0.0f) }

val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
exoPlayer?.apply {
    val runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            progress.value =
                exoPlayer.currentPosition.toFloat() / exoPlayer.duration.toFloat()
            currentInstructionDescription.value = InstructionsDescriptionBuilder.build(
                context,
                (resources.documentCenterImageUiViewModel as OnBoardingCenterImageUIViewModel.DocumentResource).step,
                exoPlayer.currentPosition.toInt() / 1000
            )
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
        }
    }
    handler.post(runnable)
}
```

I tried disposing the handler like this:

```
val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
    onDispose {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    }
}
```

**But that did not solve the problem. Any ideas?**

**EDIT**
The issue is solved thanks CommonsWare! We switched to the LaunchedEffect and coroutines for an every-second in-composition timer, rather than Handler

Comment: "The problem is that buttonAction leaks" -- what exactly do you mean? Do you mean that the `buttonAction` is referenced after the fragment is destroyed? If so, and if you believe that the outstanding reference comes from `composeOnBoardingView()`, then that implies that your composition is still around. At what point are you updating some state to cause recomposition that clears out what you set up in `composeOnBoardingView()`?

Comment: Does this [answer helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095595/why-recomposition-happens-when-call-viewmodel-in-a-callback)? not sure what's `navigate`, but you can try passing it by reference like `::navigate`

Comment: @CommonsWare much help! We have edited the post, it should help :)

Comment: FWIW, I would [use `LaunchedEffect` and coroutines](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect) for an every-second in-composition timer, rather than `Handler`. Or, I would move the timer logic into a viewmodel and have it update some state that triggers recomposition that in turn updates the UI.