# Why is lambda shown inside Arugument: Different section even though I have not changed the reference to lambda?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image: screenshot of Android Studio Debugger showing Recomposition State]

I have pointed/highlighted two areas of concern as seen in the above screenshot. My question is why is `onValueChange`, which is a lambda, shown inside `Different` section in the print out of `Recomposition State` object? I have not changed the reference to lambda since it points to the same reference id `@28180` in each recomposition.

I tried all the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69098713)  but still `onValueChange` is flagged as different during recomposition. I would expect it to  be under Same section like `labelRes` and `supportingTtext`. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not familiar with the debugging tool that your screenshot shows, Would the lambda end up in the `Different` section if just one variable that is used inside the lambda had changed?